# Mobile Friendly Paypal Grand Permission Web View

Tags: paypal

I am adding Paypal functionality to an iOS app, and am requesting permissions to do things on behalf of the user.  This works, however it isn't mobile friendly.

The url: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_grant-permission&request_token=something

is not responsive, and does not display nicely within a mobile web view.

[image: poor display]

What are my options for making this user experience better?
Is there a way to get a responsive view of the grant permission page?
Is there another way to allow users to grant permissions that does not require the presentation of this web view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is more or less use the [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#invoicing), now that it has thankfully been made available for Invoicing.

Comment: If you are using adaptive payments the REST API doesn't work so you have to use the webview that isn't mobile friendly.